# Qt: do I need a mutex if there is only one writer thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

configuration:debug  result: program exit with code 0.

configuration:release  result: main thread infinite loops,wont jump out of the loop(t.n==0 is true).

how can I get out of the loop ?

Only one writer thread,so I didnot use any mutex.

qt5.13 vs2017

main.cpp:

```
//#include"QtTestProg.h"
#include<QApplication>
#include<QMessageBox>
#include<QThread>
class MyThread :public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    int n = 0, m = 1;
    void run()override;
};
void MyThread::run()
{
    for (; m;) {
        QThread::msleep(3000);
        n = 1;
    }
}
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyThread t;
    t.start();
    for (; 1;)
    {
        if (t.n != 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    t.m = 0;
    t.quit();
    t.wait();
    return 0;
}
#include"main.moc"
```

Comment: Your QThread is reading the value of `m` and the `main()` thread is writing the value of `m`, which means that access to `m` must be synchronized via a mutex (or alternatively `m` must be changed to an atomic type) otherwise you're invoking undefined behavior.  (same problem with `n` except that the roles of the two threads are reversed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only one writer thread,so I didnot use any mutex.

That's undefined behavior. If you read and write the same memory location from different threads, you need synchronization. From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model

> When an evaluation of an expression writes to a memory location and another evaluation reads or modifies the same memory location, the expressions are said to conflict. A program that has two conflicting evaluations has a data race unless
>
> - both evaluations execute on the same thread or in the same signal handler, or
> - both conflicting evaluations are atomic operations (see std::atomic), or
> - one of the conflicting evaluations happens-before another (see std::memory_order)
>
> If a data race occurs, the behavior of the program is undefined.

You either need a mutex guarding both reads and writes or use `std::atomic_int`/`QAtomicInt` instead of plain `int` for `m` and `n`.

As for the consequences of the undefined behavior, [here (godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrRABmUlfQAZPLUwAcs4ARpjEIABspAAOqEKE5rR2ji7uMXEJdL7%2BQU6h4VHGmKaJDATMxATJzq4eRSV0ZRUE2YEhYZFG5ZXVqXXdLX5teR0RAJRGqA7EyBxSOm5%2ByI5YANSabjbMRE54Wm7YmjIAggtLK5jrm8gIxHSoG4cnZ7TLDmsbNgS3mMzoj0dTicHPF1KsACoATVE2CuABFVn4CBt9CcAPRokF%2BYAQ6GwjYIoQEdAgEDbVC7ZAAfSRKMBgKRqyczD8EDG6wA7KjjqteassWDaMwnJghNFmLNVkSSShbvcqaxCGE2EI6Sc%2BbiYataJouTJdXC1Ty%2BVCtU5dbpOAajYCNcwHERVt94VLiaTvsRfugILaNXzNABWfTaCKBuFszncv3R1Y0YirH1uXRMlHsi2%2BmMx6XuhB4IRUj1e0lCdiYaJUuMQbQyGtOIRjI2ZzO0F1WpMZpvW9Uxg0N9vPbu8uMJlGrNu6BuDyMdjV4KgJltgMAE1YySfG6PpqeZ4Ke5gAa0bPY5hqnXaBG6ZLv1/cv3wAdApUKy%2B9zz1IJqxpAH5K5ZPJUGkGwDAMKUphmS4Fk4eQCGkOQxgmfcQG4ABOe9OADDkAxkFCMKwnCMJUaRuHkJwQADCJ720NwOTcNxOAADm0FCZA5bQGN4P85FIQCpHkIQQBkUhYP/CY4FgGBEBQClojwdgyAoCA0CcWT5JAYBOE4bQ%2BDkggwgEiBgjg%2BRgj8CoAE9pGg0hlJFegAHlaFYSz/1ILBmXUdhjLcvBPRKAA3UVvMwcRigdOZuKRTAv1cxVdwsuwsG8ghiDwMipGgiYqFUYAhAANTwTAAHd7OiKwrPkfhGBYLyeD4OgCGEMRJFcpROBUNQNBAvQVDwYIBMgCZUGiMw6AEqQAFp7O0VYJtYEafj%2BfjouKUbXAgLxelcdqvFaXJ8mUWJ4jWrbDoyNa9vacJ2vqNamh6ewamUW7SgGS6RmurpmlOm63qGfaOk4CYhHA2YuE/b9f283jxAYiIJoibhVmAZBkDHTgqITYC9AMUhVlwQgSHWaj2tWOwVLksJifosYYOMhDSAQL0OjZUgkOwoipBI0gyI5riAOkfjBOE%2BnSHEqSpgIaIHXIShlNUwHPHwIhPqqpg2A4OqqqaiRvKK4hmGiCqIakH9SH5njpHsh1pYIVZUHnWH4cR5HUfRzGIHJhX4yg2mRdEiYmb%2BFmTe53mhIt3ihaEkT4MQ8iZHvDjtFQmRk9TjjObcKHXKj/24857RSK4Gt7xrcuK4r9rI8F/OPwmQLiHiCxuCAA%3D%3D) you can see that gcc at O2 level compiles out the loop in the `main()` entirely unless you change `TYPE` from `int` to `std::atomic_int` at the top.

Comment: It does not seem to eliminate loop in any case in godbolt, as far as I see. Are you sure?

Comment: @Ozgur That's how I interpret no highlighted background. [Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWc10.png) with `printf()` added before and after the loop, where it is visible better. You can also run it and see that there is no delay between messages unless you change the `TYPE` to `std::atomic_int`. 
If you run it inside godbolt though, you will probably have to add current time to those messages to see a difference.

Answer (score 2):

This loop:

```
    for (; 1;)
    {
        if (t.n != 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Technically, the above code could literally run forever even if the compiler sees that `t.n` is not getting modified. It could, theoretically, cache the value in a register or optimize it out. There's also the cache-coherency issue associated to doing lockless programming.

Three options:

1. Use [std::atomic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) to have a fast lock-like and thread safe semantics on a single variable.
2. Just use a [std::mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and [std::lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) around the assignment and evaluation of `t.n`.
3. Use a [condition variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) such that the main thread waits for `n` to change until the running thread signals that it has changed.

Comment: :   i dont understand : why ' the above code could literally run forever'?

Comment: @kenash0625 - Here's a simple example validated by assembly: https://www.godbolt.org/z/adnKbzE6Y  The compiler in this case will stuff the value of `n` into the `eax` register and just test if it's zero.  If it is zero, it just does a jump back to the `test` line to continue evaluating the eax register.  So even if `n` is changed by another thread, the loop will continue forever.

Comment: thanks. i switch between -O1   -O2  -O0 , find that the compiler did a lot of things.  i should review assembly language now

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `QReadWriteLock`. This class is designed for your cases, when you need several readers not to block each other.